# Page jumps on jquery radio button

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have a menu consisting of several items and I want to change their prices as their radio buttons are clicked in the options.
I used the following code to change prices:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("input:radio[type=radio]").click(function () {
                this.preventDefault();

                var value = $(this).val();
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var base_price = $(this).attr('base_price');

                var arr_rbtn_id = value.split(',');
                var newprice = parseFloat(arr_rbtn_id[0]) + parseFloat(base_price);
                $(".pid" + arr_rbtn_id[2]).html(priceFormat(newprice));
                return false;

            });
       });
```

I've been trying to resolve this issue by putting preventdefault but no use please help,

Comment: please provide your html, so far the only problem i see is that you should have this instead: `...click( function(e) {  e.preventDefault();...`

Comment: `preventDefault` is not a method of DOM elements, it's a method of events, so `this.preventDefault()` should be reporting an error.

Comment: can you add a fiddle/jsbin?

Comment: `:radio` is the same as `[type=radio]`, you don't need both in the selector.

Comment: why are you retrieving the `id` if it is not being used?

Comment: you're right Im not using it any more, but could this be the reason for problem?

Answer (score 0):

So far, the problems i see with your code is that you have a wrong way of calling your radio element and that `this.preventDefault` is not needed. I made some changes, give this a try. If there are more errors, add some of your HTML above so we can help you.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[type=radio]").click(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var base_price = $(this).attr('base_price');

            var arr_rbtn_id = value.split(',');
            var newprice = parseFloat(arr_rbtn_id[0]) + parseFloat(base_price);
            $(".pid" + arr_rbtn_id[2]).html(priceFormat(newprice));
            return false;
        });
   });
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem I've noticed something else that the problem occurs in chrome not in Firefox, any clue?